# Securing OAuth clientId/clientSecret in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, security, oauth, token, secret-key

I know this is probably an age-old question, but...are there any best practices for securing client secrets for performing OAuth2 authentication in AngularJS applications? I've been racking my brain trying to think of a solution to providing truly secure access to an API from modern style web applications (they need not necessarily be AngularJS.) In my experience, adding layers of abstraction and obfuscation really don't do anything to improve security...they just make cracking the security egg more difficult for any prospective hackers (however many of them prefer a good challenge, so all your really doing is just making the hack more fun.)

Aside from the obvious ineffective solutions such as obfuscation and convolution of code and things like that, are there any best practices for securing client secrets in modern day web applications? I know these questions arose with desktop client apps, and I don't believe there was ever a solution beyond "Might as well obfuscate, that'll slow hackers down". Are we in the same boat with web apps? Is there no real solution to this problem?

If there is not a solution...is there even really any point in securing REST APIs with OAuth?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remember that ***OAuth*** is less about protecting against impersonation and more about protecting credentials. 3rd parties authenticated a user's identity for you without exposing the user's credentials. Since Tokens are not credentials, the amount of harm a hacker can do and his window to act are limited.

But ***OAuth*** is not inherently more secure for your application than regular username/pwd authentication. And on client-side apps, all your code is available for the world to see! As
you mentioned, client-side encryption is a questionable strategy.

---

**While there aren't established best practices for protecting client interactions, here are some approaches to minimize your exposure:**

**1) SSL:** Silver bullet? Maybe. The more you can use ***SSL*** in your site and your requests, the safer your users' requests will be. I honestly believe all privileged requests should be made by encrypted requests.

**2) Short Token Life-Span:** The shorter the life-span of your Token, the less incentive/advantage of sniffing it.

OAuth 2.0 creates a constant chatter out of authentication by exchanging Authentication Tokens for Refresh Tokens for Authentication Tokens. You, as the developer are now developing a chatty app that does a lot of "what's your token, here's another token, ask me for a token, here's your new token... so what do you want?" ... "oops, time's up, where's your Refresh Token?"

If that sounds like a pain, it kind of is. OAuth 2.0 is designed to make the process easier for you the developer. But the important point is, the shorter the life span of your tokens, the harder for a hacker to maintain a fraudulent identity.
**[Refresh Token reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-1.5)**

**3) Enforce your Domain:** Want to give sniffers less chance of abusing the chinks in your armor? Don't allow Cross Domain Requests!

Sure, we often have distributed environments. But if your Facade is on the Client's Domain, your exposure is lessened (word choice questionable).

Force the hacker to use your domain, limit their creativity.

**4) Use 3rd party API's for maintaining you access as often as possible:** ***Google*** and ***Facebook*** API's and Services have been unit tested, battle tested, and evolved. The more you can lean on them to maintain your user's Identity, the less work you will do and fewer chances you take.

**5) Check IP addresses:** Almost anything can be faked, but the hacker must know that IP Address is part of your validation. This is the least assured of all practices, but combined with 1,2, or more, the gaps for hackers to exploit get smaller and the payoffs for effort fade.

**6) Use a "Secret" or 2nd parameter:** You can pass your users more than tokens. You can pass your own Alter-Token.

Pretend it's an ID data being passed back and forth. Name the param in a non-obvious way. Make it a number (e.g. age, height, address). The important point is, your hacker knows little or nothing of what's being asked for on the other side!

You can throw a serious monkey-wrench by having 3 params that act as security.

**7)** Don't give error messages to inform the hacker they've been caught. Give timeout msgs rather than "Got You!" If the invaders don't realize the fraud was caught they don't adapt as well.

---

**I can't say it enough -- SSL saves a lot of trouble.**

**Note:** All client Providers I have seen allow access to their API's without exposing Secret. **Secret should never be exposed on client.**

- Any data exposed on client can be gleamed
- Any encryption algorithm you use, will be exposed on the client.

Comment: I love your answer. It is a great explanation for a noob like myself getting into client side to API communication. In my case I control both sides. the API side is a python/django API that uses OAuth. It takes a client id, client secret, username and password and returns an auth token and refresh token.

In my case, is it okay that the client secret is visible? For some reason this doesn't sit easy with me.

Comment: @farcrats, your hesitation is spot on -- your "Secret" should never be openly revealed. Always use SSL encryption. But you can also use your own psuedo-secret -- Give each user a special code you store. I like to use something like 'Height:12inch', 'age:53'. I store this data in exact format and expect a "pretend parameter like height or age for the user (again should have no relevance to real data). This way you have created another form of authentication that a hacker wouldn't even know is part of the authentication process.

Comment: Thanks Dave. We are using SSL. I'll implement something as you suggested. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I totally agree, SSL saves a lot of trouble. Sometimes it's not what the business want's to do, though. I've tried to explain how OAuth isn't exactly secure, but they are set in their ways, I guess.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question. None of these is a way of properly hiding a client-secret in the in-browser javascript app.  Dave Syer has talked about actual solutions for this (might be one here, I think https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) that involve actually breaking out of the "pure JS SPA" pattern temporarily and loading a "protected" resource (a file with the client secret) from a server.

Comment: @Rhubarb, I get your point, but I don't think this is a reasonable downvote or critique. The answer in comments, though not outright stated, was to never reveal the secret on the UI side. Secret should be used from the Server side and when used should always be encrypted. If you like, I could edit the answer to reflect that. But to argue that my answer is invalid b/c I didn't openly address this is unreasonable. The answer could easily be edited to better answer your point.

Comment: @Rhubarb, I don't think the article you sent did not address client secret. And, again, my sincere belief is that Secret should never be exposed on the client. The client "belongs" to the user in practical every way.

Comment: @Rhubarb, I amended my answer to include (as I should have earlier) that Secret should never be exposed on client. All API's I have used to date do not require Secret from client side. And they should not.If you disagree, please explain why and give me some good references and I will change my answer. Do you still find my answer lacking?

Comment: @Rhubarb, I have not had any response from you. I adjusted my answer to reflect that I don't believe that Secrets should ever be used on Client and my reasons why. Do you feel I have answered the question better now? Would you suggest any improvements? Was your critique meant to be constructive or to belittle?

Comment: @Rhubarb, are you actually interested in this question? I've tried communicating on your concern repeatedly. Frankly, I don't think you have a point at all. I suspect you enjoy nitpicking and nagging, but have no interest beyond that. If I am wrong, please clarify.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich "SSL silver bullet", "SSL will save you a lot of troube"...can you please explain how SSL will protect you against CSRF attacks? Or against XSS attacks? Or any sort of attacks coming from your own browser such as this nice js library you downloaded from npm or some random CDN that is hijacking your cookies and localstorage?

Comment: @Leo, XSS and CSRF attacks are not issues specific OAuth apps. Same with Man-in-the-middle type attacks (eg malicious web extensions). You made some good points in your deleted answer. They don't have to be communicated with hostility for people to listen to you. In fact, if someone overlooked something and you suggest it, they will probably listen if you learn how to communicate without hostility. I suggest you take Anthony's advice and learn to collaborate rather than defecate.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I didn't get your point...I never said (and would never say) XSS and CSRF attacks are specific to "OAuth apps". As for the rest of your comment, why are you still dragging on such unconstructive subject? There is not one single element of hostility on my deleted answer...it's you who seem to be taking it so personal because I pointed out  that your answer is misleading? I thought it was all about collaboration...

Comment: @DaveAlperovich There is also the nonce and timestamp included in the token to prevent replay attacks - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for the answer to this very question - how to handle the secret/id in an SPA. I came up with my own solution that hides the secret in the server but I wanted to confirm what I was doing was best practice. So since answers avoid this I will explain my flow in hopes that it will help anyone out there.

Our architecture - we have a ruby server as the api server and an express server serving up the Angular app.

Normally all communication is simply done RESTfully thru the api so the node server is just serving static files and not really doing a whole lot.

Since we were at the point of implementing the login/signup flows I came across the - what was new to me - OAuth 2.0 flow of how to handle things.

Before we can make any requests to the server and the server will take us seriously we need to get ourselves the Bearer token. I chose to implement it as a node endpoint thus to hide the client secret inside the node server itself.

So our customer has entered all their juicy data and are redy to become a user in our app they hit the submit button.

1. The app fires the request to the node server to get ourselves a yummy token that we can use as the Bearer. I chose to pass the client id as a GET request query parameter. First off I had both client id and secret in the node server but it felt like the id could/should be on the, well, client. So I went with this way.
2. The node server receives the client id thru the GET request and then proceeds to fire the POST to the host(ruby api). Constructing the url + grant type + client id + client secret. Thus hiding the implementation from the world.
3. The ruby server return a token for us to use which we then return to the client that initialized the signup request.
4. The SPA now has a Bearer token which we can use in the header of the signup request.

Thus completing our flow and having a hidden cient secret from the world.

Since we have a token with a certain lifespan we also have a request error interceptor that will catch tokens that have expired and thus make a new token request and then refire the failed call.

I have chosen to use on the Angular side of things this lib for users flow.

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Its a super handy lib that gets all the boring boilerplate code that has to be written every time we want an app to have authentication thru email/password and also thru oauth....very handy.

So since this is my own interpretation of how to do such things - feedback is kindly requested.

Comment: Hi Sten, like yourself, I have read this post trying to find out how to keep secrets in a SPA app. I have some questions about your approach (possibly because I am also new to this). 1. Do you have just one client application? 2. What happens when an existing user logs in (with the client secret?) 3. What is to stop anyone with the (public?) client ID from attempting to log in (as it appears that the client app never gets told what the secret is)? - These are probably noob questions, but just some stuff that I couldn't figure out from your write-up. Thanks

Comment: 1 yr later - Oauth 2.0 is retarded. Just go with JSON Web Tokens (JWT). Use them as the Bearer token thru Satelizer (if you are using Angular), they got all the goods on them and personally make the most sense are the most flexible and cannot be faked as the backend is the issuer. 99.999% infallible in my opinion...